# How can I create a stopwatch in bash?

Tags: bash, math, time, timer, bash-function

I created a simple stopwatch (bash function) for counting time, but for now it's showing current time with milliseconds.

The code:

```
function stopwatch() {
    date +%H:%M:%S:%N
    while true; do echo -ne "`date +%H:%M:%S:%N`\r"; done;
}
```

I tried to change it as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35312857/2831106), but it works only with second since Unix Epoch.

When I used `date` format `+%s.%N` the subtraction from the answer above stopped working due to the fact that bash subtraction takes only integer.

How can I solve it and have a terminal stopwatch that prints time like so:

```
0.000000000
0.123123123
0.435345345
(and so on..)
```

?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One possible (& hacky) mechanism that can work for a day:

```
$ now=$(date +%s)sec
$ while true; do
     printf "%s\r" $(TZ=UTC date --date now-$now +%H:%M:%S.%N)
     sleep 0.1
  done
```

Bonus: You can press enter at any time to get the *LAP* times. *;-)*

Note: This is a quick fix. Better solutions should be available...

`watch` based variant (same logic):

```
$ now=$(date +%s)sec; watch -n0.1 -p TZ=UTC date --date now-$now +%H:%M:%S.%N
```

Comment: Won't the nanoseconds always be off?

Comment: No. Nanoseconds are on and this is even better than my old solution (in another answer). Great! (although I also added some sleep due to CPU usage :-) )

Comment: @lewiatan You may aswell use milli/microseconds if you are using sleep.

Comment: @123: I just translated OP's code & added date subtraction logic.

Comment: @anishsane Yes, i was mistaken, i thought the nanaseconds would be off due to only using seconds for the starting date, apparently it doesn't matter though.

Comment: @123 - Yes I could if they would be supported by `date` but since it's only nanoseconds and I don't want any extra calculations I prefer executing this less often.

Comment: This will eat up quite some resources. Adding a sleep will improve this. I'm aware that OP mentioned milliseconds. Assuming that this is for human readability (and interaction) I think a small sleep like `sleep 0.1s` might be a good compromise.

Comment: My god. This is beautifull!

Answer (score 18):

If you want something simple that includes minutes, seconds, and centiseconds like a traditional stopwatch you could use [sw](https://github.com/coryfklein/sw).

[image: sw]

## Install

```
wget -q -O - http://git.io/sinister | sh -s -- -u https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coryfklein/sw/master/sw
```

## Usage

```
# start a stopwatch from 0, save start time in ~/.sw
sw

# resume the last run stopwatch
sw --resume
```

Comment: To anyone looking at this after Jul, 2020. The app seems to be broken!

Comment: I just installed it fresh on macOS Catalina 10.15.5 and it worked no problem. Feel free to file an issue on GitHub with your details @KarthikNayak.

Comment: There is a pending issue with the same issue here: https://github.com/coryfklein/sw/issues/2

Comment: Worked for me today.

Comment: Since this technically doesn't answer the OP and a good number of us coming here are just looking for a functional terminal stopwatch, [termdown](https://github.com/trehn/termdown) has more features (if that's what one wants). Found via [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/764336/988483).

Answer (score 12):

```
time cat
```

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> to stop the timer and show the time. The first number is the time.

I've further refined it into this bash alias

```
alias stopwatch="echo Press Ctrl-c to stop the timer; TIMEFORMAT=%R; time cat; unset TIMEFORMAT"
```

Comment: plus1. Another possibility is to use `read -n1` instead of `cat`. Then Any character would terminate it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nicer function I grabbed a while ago:

```
function stopwatch() {
    local BEGIN=$(date +%s)
    echo Starting Stopwatch...

    while true; do
        local NOW=$(date +%s)
        local DIFF=$(($NOW - $BEGIN))
        local MINS=$(($DIFF / 60))
        local SECS=$(($DIFF % 60))
        local HOURS=$(($DIFF / 3600))
        local DAYS=$(($DIFF / 86400))

        printf "\r%3d Days, %02d:%02d:%02d" $DAYS $HOURS $MINS $SECS
        sleep 0.5
    done
}
```

In response to a comment, here's a version that will exit once the user presses the Enter key:

```
function stopwatch_with_cancel() {
    local BEGIN=$(date +%s)
    echo Starting Stopwatch...

    while true; do
        local NOW=$(date +%s)
        local DIFF=$(($NOW - $BEGIN))
        local MINS=$(($DIFF / 60))
        local SECS=$(($DIFF % 60))
        local HOURS=$(($DIFF / 3600))
        local DAYS=$(($DIFF / 86400))

        printf "\r%3d Days, %02d:%02d:%02d" $DAYS $HOURS $MINS $SECS
        read -rsN1 -t1 key
        if [ "$key" == $'\x0a' ] ;then
            # echo -e "\n [Enter] Pressed"
            break
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: doesn't your `MINS` need to mod 60? or else your `MINS` might show as 61 or 200. And then, the same with `HOURS`... need to mod 24

Comment: Can this be modified to be stopped when the user hits Enter?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [a gist by rawaludin](https://gist.github.com/rawaludin/9c24bf900d798d66ce29):

```
function stopwatch() {
  local BEGIN=$(date +%s)

  while true; do
    local NOW=$(date +%s)
    local DIFF=$(($NOW - $BEGIN))
    local MINS=$(($DIFF / 60 % 60))
    local SECS=$(($DIFF % 60))
    local HOURS=$(($DIFF / 3600 % 24))
    local DAYS=$(($DIFF / 86400))
    local DAYS_UNIT
    [ "$DAYS" == 1 ] && DAYS_UNIT="Day" || DAYS_UNIT="Days"

    printf "\r  %d %s, %02d:%02d:%02d  " $DAYS $DAYS_UNIT $HOURS $MINS $SECS
    sleep 0.25
  done
}
```

For people who are not familiar with this: in English, only when it is `1` do we use singular -- Day. When it is 0, 2, 3, 4, 5..., we use plural
 "Days", so note that it is `0 Days`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take on a bash stopwatch, drawing much from other answers in this thread. Ways in which this version differs from the others include:

- This version uses bash arithmetic rather than calling `bc` which I found (by timing it) to be way less cpu time.
- I have addressed the 25th-hour limitation that someone had pointed out by tacking 24 hours onto the hour part for every day elapsed. (So now I guess it's the ~31st-day limitation.)
- I leave the cursor just to the right of the output, unlike the version in the accepted answer. That way you can easily measure laps (or more generally mark important event times) just by hitting enter, which will move the timer to the next line, leaving the time at keypress visible.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

start_time=$(date +%s)

while true; do
  current_time=$(date +%s)
  seconds_elapsed=$(( $current_time - $start_time ))
  timestamp=$(date -d"@$seconds_elapsed" -u +%-d:%-H:%-M:%-S)

  IFS=':' read -r day hour minute second <<< "$timestamp"
  hour="$(( $hour+24*($day-1) ))"

  printf "\r%02d:%02d:%02d" $hour $minute $second
  sleep 0.5
done;
```

Here is sample output from running `stopwatch` (as an executable script in the PATH) and hitting the return key at 7 and 18 seconds, and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> after about 9 minutes:

```
$ stopwatch
00:00:07
00:00:18
00:09:03^C
$
```

Notes:

- I use the `+%-d:%-H:%-M:%-S` output format for date (this dashes mean "leave off any leading zero please") because printf seems to interpret digit strings with a leading zero as octal and eventually complains about invalid values.
- I got rid of the nanoseconds simply because for my purposes I don't need beyond 1-second precision. Therefore I adjusted the `sleep` duration to be longer to save on compute.

Answer (score 0):

For the subtraction you should use `bc` (`An arbitrary precision calculator language`).

Here is the example code that fulfill your requirements:

```
function stopwatch() {
    date1=`date +%s.%N`
    while true; do
        curr_date=`date +%s.%N`
        subtr=`echo "$curr_date - $date1" | bc`
        echo -ne "$subtr\r";
        sleep 0.03
    done;
}
```

Additional `sleep` is added to lower the CPU usage (without it on my machine it was almost 15% and with this `sleep` it lowered to 1%).

Comment: You can certainly improve this slightly: you don't need the `curr_date` variable if you directly use: `subtr=$(date "+%s.%N-$date1" | bc)`. You're saving one subshell on each iteration! You could also put `bc` out of the loop, and then use another loop to replace the `\n` output by `bc` by a `\r`.

Comment: Something like: `stopwatch() { local a date1=$(date +%s.%N); while :; do date "+%s.%N-$date1"; sleep 0.03; done | bc | while read a; do printf '%s\r' "$a"; done; }`. With the `printf` you can use another format too, e.g., `printf '%.3f\r' "$a"`.